# Escrever em Imagem com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, imagem

Pesquisei sobre, mas não encontro conteúdo algum!

Como no PHP existe a [ImageString](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi1-8aVgPPXAhXMg5AKHYj6B5QQFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fpt_BR%2Ffunction.imagestring.php&usg=AOvVaw0rPCChF7S2k7C7x87WqvHB), para escrever sobre as imagens, existe alguma biblioteca no JS que tenha a mesma função ?

### Cenário:

Tenho uma imagem que vai servir de template pro usuário, quero que ele digite no formulário que vai existir, nome, ramal e cargo, e deve aparecer na imagem, e que ele possa salvá-la depois.

Alguém conhece alguma solução?!

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo onde escrevo com [Canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) em uma imagem:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var canvas = $("#myCanvas")[0];
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function(){
     context.drawImage(imageObj, 10, 10);
     context.font = "20px Calibri";
     context.fillStyle = 'white';
     imageObj.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
     context.fillText("https://obscure.network", 70, 50);

     // open the image in a new browser tab
     // the user can right-click and save that image
     $(document.body).append("<img src='"+canvas.toDataURL()+"'/>");  

 };
 imageObj.src = "https://i.imgur.com/8Yf5rt1.jpg"; 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
```